# how do i invoked when there is no match of the prefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## inform user that there was no match

## if description given, add an entry to the dictionary

```
def find_matches(prefix, entries):
    
   for entry in entries:
        
     if prefix in entry[:]:     
       break

        else:
            print(f'"{prefix}": NO match')
            add = str(input('Enter description (or leave blank to ignore)> '))
            if add != '':
                entries[prefix] = add
                print(f'new entry: {prefix} -- {entries[prefix]}')

    return entries
```

lets say the entries are 'blue,coffe,cup,dog' (entries are dictionary keys)

this is my code and every time a prefix is 'co' it iterates 'else:' which makes no sense because it is in the entries 'co' in 'coffe', or even 'dog'. how do i fix it?

Comment: Your indentation is broken, please correct it

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of indentation errors in your code above. I can't see why it is not working. The code below works. I have added a print statement in the if so you can see it passes there.

```
entries = ['blue', 'coffe', 'cup', 'dog']

def find_matches(prefix, entries):

    for entry in entries:

        if prefix in entry[:]:
            print(f'"{prefix} in {entry}": MATCH')
            break

        else:
           print(f'"{prefix} in {entry}": NO match')
           add = str(input('Enter description (or leave blank to ignore)> '))
           if add != '':
                entries[prefix] = add
                print(f'new entry: {prefix} -- {entries[prefix]}')

    return entries

find_matches('co', entries)
```

Result

```
"co in blue": NO match
Enter description (or leave blank to ignore)> 
"co in coffe": MATCH   <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```